# Undefined variable: <variable Name> in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

helpers.php is a helper module with a function `voteAppeal`

```
function voteAppeal($appealId) {
  $userLogin = .....//working fine

  $voteAppeal = .....//working fine

  if(Auth::user()->id == $userLogin->id) {
    View::share('voteAppeal', $voteAppeal);
  } else {
    View::share('voteAppeal', '');
  }
}
```

I am trying to use it in the noti.blade.php module to check to log all votes received

```
  @if($voteAppeal != '')
    @foreach($voteAppeal as $voteAppeal)
      @if($voteAppeal->read == 0)
        someone Voted you.. //working fine for my code
      @endif
    @endforeach
  @endif
```

But it shows the following error:

```
Undefined variable: voteAppeal (View:....\noti.blade.php)
```

Any idea?

Comment: There is a problem here `$voteAppeal as $voteAppeal` change the second variable name and try again !

Comment: You're overwriting your original `$voteAppeal` here: `@foreach($voteAppeal as $voteAppeal)`

Comment: this is not the problem, it working fine like this... but I'll change it.

Comment: if I call voteAppeal($appealId) ( Eg: voteAppeal(22)) from a controller, error is gone.. but that is not the way to call...

Comment: Why you use `View::share` ?

Comment: because I want to share this function with all views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the variable to each and every blade by helper, rather you should place calls to share within a service provider's boot method. You are free to add them to the AppServiceProvider or generate a separate service provider to house, that is why it's giving error.

Check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views

And also done the changes in foreach loop.
I hope it will help you.

Comment: Did you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the second variable here `$voteAppeal as $voteAppeal` because it overrides your original variable (`$voteAppeal`) :

```
@if($voteAppeal != '')
    @foreach($voteAppeal as $voteApp)
        @if($voteApp->read == 0)
            someone Voted you..
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

And the second problem is that you have to attach the sharing with a view using the [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers) !

Or you can use `AppServiceProvider`, in the boot method you can call your method `voteAppeal`, with that you will share the the variables with all the views.

Comment: can you share your View Composers link... I read the document but didn't understand everything

Comment: Check the update :), there is one problem with it, i mean the parameter of you method !

Comment: your comments help a lot, and I have one question, I want to see the noti.blade.php from all page (home, user, etc) but if I didn't call the function name from each controller (homeController etc) it cannot display the data. but if I put a function name inside my controller like (voteAppeal(22)) and it is showing the data i want, but I want a real data->id and display on all pages, how can I change that

Comment: From where you get the variable `data` ?

Comment: I have `NotificationController`, but I don't really know how my model `helpers.php` and the controller will interact, I don't wanna create a Route to link them, whenever a new notification is there (new data in notification table) I wanna show to the user on every page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167809/discussion-between-maraboc-and-vpa).